# I want FIRDataEventTypeChildChanged instead of ChildRemoved called when a child is changed to nil?

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want `FIRDataEventTypeChildChanged` instead of `ChildRemoved` called when a child is changed to nil.  I only want `ChildRemoved` called when the root object being observed is deleted (set to `nil`).  Is there any easy work around this or must I hack around it by setting children fields to some random value like "gdgdsfdsfsadfsdNIL" instead of deleting them and then changing any value that is such to `nil` on the front end?

Comment: Maybe if you told us why do want this kind of customisation, helping you would be easier? Is it because of bandwidth usage concerns?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to program against the core principle in the SDK, which might'n be the best idea.

By design the ChildRemoved will be called when the node is being set to `nil` (`Null` in fact).

If you really want this behaviour the best way to do it, in my opinion, would be to set your values (in case of a string) to `""` (an empty string) and so on. But it might translate into some problems later on, plus you have to allow for empty values in your rules.

Answer (score 0):

Setting a value to null in the Firebase Database is by definition equivalent to deleting the node. There is no way to change this behavior.